# Is there a bash equivalent to a PowerShell pipeline object?

Tags: bash, powershell

In PowerShell, I could run something like this in a one-liner

```
Get-ChildItem | foreach {
  if ($_ -match '.+?\.py$' -eq $true) {
    $_ | Do-Thing -WithFile
  }
  if ($_ -match '.+?\.pdf$' -eq $true) {
    $_ | Do-Thing -WithOtherFile
  }
}
```

like so

```
Get-ChildItem | foreach { if ($_ -match '.+?\.py$' -eq $true) { $_ | Do-Thing -WithFile } if ($_ -match '.+?\.pdf$' -eq $true) { $_ | Do-Thing -WithOtherFile } }
```

The specific functionality of this that I appreciate is being able to reference the pipeline object via `$_` to be used in the next command and being able to do conditional execution based on split pieces of output via `| foreach {}`.

I know in bash it'd be easy to grep multiple patterns at once via

```
> ls | egrep '\.py$|\.pdf$'

some_foo.py
some_bar.py
foo.pdf
bar.pdf
```

Is it possible to extend on this in a one liner with what's available by default where I'd be able to do the equivalent of

```
| foreach { if ($_ -match '.+?\.py$') {Do-Thing -With $_ } if (...) { Do-Thing -WithOther $_ } }
```

or does Bash only redirect stdout of one command to the stdin of another? I find a lot of misc uses for this dynamic in PowerShell but have not heard of an equivalent in Bash.

This isn't anything blocking and writing a script in the usual syntax works fine, I was just curious because it's incredibly helpful in PS.

Looking for: `$_ , | foreach {}` equivalents where I could split the output, check conditions on it, then be able to reference the split piece of output via some name. In PSs case, $_

I do know there are many ways PS is fundamentally different from Bash so I would not be surprised if this was specific to PS.

For better context, here's an example in PS where you'd search recursively for files with python and pdf extensions and make a log of them in their respective text files

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | foreach {
  if ($_ -match '.+?\.py$' -eq $true) {
    $_ | Out-File -encoding utf8 -Append py_list.txt
  }
  if ($_ -match '.+?\.pdf$' -eq $true) {
    $_ | Out-File -encoding utf8 -Append pdf_list.txt
  }
}
```

Comment: Ordinarily, `find` is the "Right Tool for the Job," when _the Job_ is defined as "do something with a bunch of files, possibly matching a pattern, recursing into subdirectories." If you wanted to, say, cheer for Python scripts and boo at PDFs, for example, you could `find . -name '*.py' -exec echo 'Yay, {}!' \; -o -name '*.pdf' -exec echo 'Boo, {}!' \;` This does not depend on any special features that only GNU `find` has (so it will work out of the box on macOS, for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes (almost) and no. Bash does not support pipelining 'objects' in the first place – its pipelines, even internal ones, are still built on subprocesses and ordinary stdio (which is a bytestream), and so you can only interact with ordinary lines of **text** (e.g. a line-by-line list of file paths), not complex objects.

So the closest equivalent would be `while read -r <var>; do ...; done`. More on that later.

---

Your *specific* task can be **best** handled using a simple `for <var> in <words>` loop with **wildcards**:

```
for file in *; do
    if [[ $file == *.py ]]; then
        do_something_with "$file"
    elif [[ $file == *.pdf ]]; then
        do_something_else --with "$file"
    fi
done
```

You don't even need to reproduce the explicit checks – you can have two loops instead:

```
for file in *.py; do
    do_something_with "$file"
done

for file in *.pdf; do
    do_something_else --with "$file"
done
```

---

To do the same **recursively**, you can a) use Bash's recursive wildcards:

```
shopt -s globstar

for file in **/*; do
    if ...; then ...; fi
done
```

or b) use `find` and loop over **each line in stdin**:

```
find . -type f | while read -r file; do
    if [[ $file == *.py ]]; then
        ...
    fi
done
```

(Yes, I should have used `IFS="" read -r <var>` to handle filenames which happen to end with a space – but fortunately I don't have any of those on my system so I won't bother.)

Once again, you can skip the manual filename checks and request what you need up-front.

```
shopt -s globstar

for file in **/*.pdf; do
    do_something_with "$file"
done
```

Variant b:

```
find . -type f -name "*.pdf" | while read -r file; do
    do_something_with "$file"
done
```

The same but making use of *find*'s -exec option:

```
find . -type f -name "*.pdf" -exec do_something_with {} \;
```

Comment: This was an excellent, informative response and I'm always grateful I can turn to the SO community for well nuanced responses. Thank you for clearing this up!

Comment: An exemplary answer, and one that I'm totally going to point my co-workers to next time I get asked "how do I do _x_ with `*.yyy` (possibly descending into subdirectories) in a Bash shell script?" `;)`